# Adding input inside component makes input get all click events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-dom

I am trying to create a component that functions as a color picker. Clicking on the `.swatch` element opens the popover (which contains a `.cover` div that extends the whole screen). Click on the cover (outside of the popover) will close the popover. Pretty standard behavior (I copied the code from [React Color examples](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#examples)).

This works fine until I add an input tag inside of `.swatch` then no matter where I click, the input click event fires.

This is what I get in the console when I click outside the popover for example:

```
handleClose
renders
click input
handleClick
renders
```

My component `ColorPickerInput.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { SketchPicker } from 'react-color'
import styles from './ColorPickerInput.scss'
import tinyColor from 'tinycolor2'

export default class ColorPickerInput extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      displayColorPicker: false,
      color: tinyColor(props.initialColorHex).toRgb(),
      colorHex: props.initialColorHex
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)
  }

  static propTypes = {
    initialColorHex: PropTypes.string,
    inputName: PropTypes.string
  }

  handleClick () {
    console.log('handleClick')
    this.setState({ displayColorPicker: !this.state.displayColorPicker })
  }

  handleChange (color) {
    this.setState({ color: color.rgb })
    this.setState({ colorHex: color.hex })
  }

  handleClose (e) {
    e.stopPropagation() // <-- I tried to add this but makes no difference

    console.log('handleClose')
    this.setState({ displayColorPicker: false })
  }

  render () {
    console.log('renders')
    const { inputName } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className={styles.swatch}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          <input type="text" readOnly onClick={() => console.log('click input')} /> {/*<--- works fine without this line */}
          <div
            className={styles.color}
            style={{backgroundColor: `rgb(${this.state.color.r}, ${this.state.color.g},${this.state.color.b})`}}
          />
        </div>
        { this.state.displayColorPicker
          ? <div className={styles.popover}>
            <div className={styles.cover} onClick={this.handleClose} />
            <SketchPicker
              color={this.state.color}
              disableAlpha
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          : null
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And here are the styles `ColorPickerInput.scss`:

```
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2
}

.cover {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0
}

.swatch {
  display: inline-flex;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.color {
  width: 36px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.hexText {
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

The input doesn't have any unusual styles applied:
[image: input]

Comment: Could you also include the jsx?

Comment: @squgeim I did that, I don't really get what jsx you are referring to

Comment: Sorry, the code didn't scroll for me. I can see it now.

Comment: If I use `type="hidden"` together with a span (basically how input readonly can be emulated) I do not have the issue. But it still puzzles me why this happens.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. This is a wild guess, but could you show the result of having event handlers for `onFocus` and `onBlur` on the input element. When are they being executed?

Comment: I actually don't know what is causing this. I have tried to reproduce it again by reverting the code to the version I posted here but no luck. Well, I guess it is not a problem for me anymore since I am not using a visible input any more. I'll come back at it if I see something similar. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stopPropagation()` on the input, which is the child-component, then the parent's clicked event will not be fired:

```
<input type="text" readOnly onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); console.log('click input');}} /> {/*<--- works fine without this line */}
```